# Optimizing 2 sets of variable length vectors

Tags: r, optimization

I did searched the questions here before posting and I found only one question in this regard but it doesn't apply to my case.

I have uploaded the data for `PRD`, `INJ`, `tao` and `lambda` with the links below, which shall be used to reproduce the code:

[PRD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/suv0as9qhy84mg9/PRD.csv)

[INJ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vcy5d4d8dluan3/INJ.csv)

[lambda](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv1pzwn6bn32gfj/lambda.csv)

[tao](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkxmwmqzorraufn/tao.csv)

the code:

```
PRD=read.csv(file="PRD.csv")
INJ=read.csv(file="INJ.csv")
PRD=do.call(cbind, PRD)
INJ=do.call(cbind, INJ)
tao=do.call(cbind, read.csv(file="tao.csv",header=FALSE))
lambda=do.call(cbind, read.csv(file="lambda.csv",header=FALSE))
fn1 <- function (tao,lambda) {
#perparing i.dash  
  i.dash=matrix(ncol=ncol(INJ), nrow=(nrow(INJ)))
  for (i in 1:ncol(INJ)){
     for (j in 1:nrow (INJ)){
      temp=0
      for (k in 1:j){
        temp=(1/tao[i])*exp((k-j)/tao[i])*INJ[k,i]+temp
      }
      
      i.dash[j,i]=temp
     }
  
  #preparing lambdaXi.dash
  
  lambda.i=matrix(ncol=ncol(INJ),nrow=nrow(INJ))
 for (i in 1: ncol(INJ)){
   lambda.i[,i]=lambda[i+1]*i.dash[,i]
 }
  
 #calc. q. hat (I need to add the pp term)
 q.hat=matrix(nrow=nrow(INJ),1 )
  for (i in 1:nrow(INJ)){
    q.hat[i,1]=sum(lambda.i[i,1:ncol(INJ)])
  target= sum((PRD[,1]-q.hat[,1])^2)
   }
  }
}
```

what I am trying to do is to minimize the value `target` by optimizing `lambda` and `tao` which the starting values will be the same as the ones uploaded above. I've used `optim` to do so but I still receive the error `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type double`

I've used many variations of `optim` and still recieve the same error.

the last syntax I've used was `optim(fn1, tao=tao, lambda=lambda, hessian=T)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The calling form of `optim` is

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
             "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

So, you need to pass the parameters first, not the function. Note that "closure" is another term for "function", which explains the error message: you have passed a function as the first argument, when `optim` expected initial parameter values.

Note also, that `optim` only optimises over the first argument of the function `fn`, so you will need to redesign your function `fn1` so it only takes a single function. For example, it could be a single vector where of the form `c(n, t1, t2,...,tn, l1, l2, l3, ... lm)` where `ti` are the components of `tao` and `li` components of `lambda` and `n` tells you how many components `tao` has.

Comment: same error keeps happening, can you list a reproducible example. another question is how can I make sure the R will optimize the target value not anything else in the function? does it work by the last mentioned variable in the function?

Comment: Anyone can shed some light on the question above

Comment: It only optimises over the *first* argument of your function.

Comment: I've modified the function but still have the problem with the optimization I am receiving the same initial values after the opim function command,  I cannot list the new code here, shall post it in a new thread ?